# Smallest $r$ such that $\sum_{k=0,\,\, i+kr = qm}^{\lfloor (n-i)/r \rfloor} \binom{n}{i + kr} = 0 \pmod n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, binomial-coefficients

I want to find the smallest positive integer $r$ such that

$$\sum_{k=0,\,\, i+kr = qm}^{\lfloor (n-i)/r \rfloor} \binom{n}{i + kr} = 0 \pmod n$$

where $n=pq$, and every $i+kr = qm$ for some $m$ is considered in the sum.  Have no idea where to start.

I'm trying to find the bound on $\text{FAC}(n,1)$ described in this [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/097.pdf).

Comment: I've edited your title to be more informative - in the future, please make your titles as specific as possible.  Also, you can use double dollar signs `$$ ... $$`to make a line of math display neatly and centered, and you can use the command `\pmod` to do a parenthesized modulo.  Cheers

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is solve for $qk' = i \pmod r$, then the points of interest are $q(k' + rk)$.

Comment: I also think $\binom{n}{qk}$ has an additive inverse $\pmod n$ of the same form.  That will certainly help.   I need to find the smallest $r$ such that all inverses are present with each coefficient.

Comment: I ask again to you: are the primes $p$ and $q$ distinct? do you know **some** positive integer $r$ such that your equality holds?

Comment: I ran some tests and it doesn't always work.  It takes irregular patterns of multiples of q for it to sum to zero in some cases.